# Scraping a messy javascript-heavy website with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape the household links from this page :

https://www.sreality.cz/en/search/to-rent/apartments?page=2

For instance, for the first apartment I would like to obtain the link with:

https://www.sreality.cz/en/detail/lease/flat/1+kt/plzen-jizni-predmesti-technicka/25873756#img=0&fullscreen=false

However the website is quite heavy on javascript. By using requests.get() I only obtain an uninformative chunk of html code:

```
from requests import get

i = 2
url = f"https://www.sreality.cz/en/search/to-rent/apartments?page={i}"
response = get(url)

print(response.text)

-----------------------------

<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ html.lang }}" ng-app="sreality" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1.0,minimal-ui">

    <!--- Nastaveni meta pres JS a ne pres Angular, aby byla nastavena default hodnota pro agenty co nezvladaji PhantomJS --->
    <title ng:bind-template="{{metaSeo.title}}">Sreality.cz â¢ reality a nemovitosti z celÃ© ÄR</title>
    <meta name="description" content="NejvÄtÅ¡Ã­ nabÃ­dka nemovitostÃ­ v ÄR. NabÃ­zÃ­me byty, domy, novostavby, nebytovÃ© prostory, pozemky a dalÅ¡Ã­ reality k prodeji i pronÃ¡jmu. Sreality.cz">
    <meta property="og:title"       content="Sreality.cz â¢ reality a nemovitosti z celÃ© ÄR">
    <meta property="og:type"        content="website">
    <meta property="og:image"       content="https://www.sreality.cz/img/sreality-logo-og.png">

-----------------------------

ETC ...
```

The question is therefore, how to proceed with some simple scraping activity for websites of this kind ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Ask the website if they offer an API to access their info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that website has a public API but looking at the API calls from the network tab I could fetch the details for your need and make it as link have a look at the below code.

Let me know if you have any questions :)

```
import time
import requests
page=2
numberofresults=20
epochmiliseconds=round(time.time() * 1000)
paramsdict={
    "category_main_cb":1,
    "category_type_cb":2,
    "page":page,
    "per_page":numberofresults,
    "tms":epochmiliseconds

}
data=requests.get("https://www.sreality.cz/api/en/v2/estates",params=paramsdict).json()
for lead in data["_embedded"]["estates"]:
    locality=lead["seo"]["locality"]
    name=lead["name"]
    hash_id=lead["hash_id"]
    typedata=[s for s in name.split(" ") if "+" in s][0].replace("\u00a0"," ").split(" ")[0]
    print(f'https://www.sreality.cz/en/detail/lease/flat/{typedata}/{locality}/{hash_id}'))
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but I am using this has an exercise to get better at web scrapping. So if you could answer the following questions: 1) how did you found out that you should use 1) https://www.sreality.cz/api/en/v2/estates 2) how did you find these were the parameters to use ? Thanks in advance

Comment: 1)before calling website open inspect element and go to network tab and you will find this API calls once the website loads it would be something like this https://prnt.sc/10yes0v (You need to find the correct request in which data is coming from) or you could use tool like fiddler(this is a better approach) to record traffic and see the specific request from where the data is coming. 2)regarding paramsdict first 4 parameters are basic understandable once and 5th "tms" parameter is nothing but current epoch in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

First ask website, if they provide any API to get the desired information.

To deal with javascript during the **scraping** only request will not work. You should go Selenium only or for scrapy in combination of scrapy-selenium. These two allow loading of javascript during scraping.

Feel free to ask if you have any other question.